# Non-decaying eigenvalues in Kernel PCA with small kernel width

Tags: clustering, pca, kernel-trick, eigenvalues

I noticed that when I use a small width kernel (RBF) with PCA, I get my desired result (clustering in this case), but I do not get decay in the eigenvalues (they stay about the same value). Is that a 'problem'? should I have used a larger kernel width? because when I do, I do get decay in the eigenvalues but I don't get the proper clustering anymore.

I would appreciate any answer that can shed some light on the subject.

Attached are two examples for widths of the RBF with clustering results (left), and the eigenvalues (on the right).

[image: Example]

Comment: This is weird. Different kernel width can certainly influence the kPCA results quite a lot (and there are some techniques to select a reasonable width), but I don't understand how one can have "non-decaying" spectrum simply by varying the kernel width. Do you maybe want to update your question with some figures illustrating the situation? Also, when you say "clustering", do you mean unsupervised clustering or supervised class separability (i.e. do you have class labels in your dataset or do you not)?

Comment: Thanks for your reponse. It is unsupervised, and I later evaluate by the real labels. I added an image to exemplify.

Comment: Hmm. Thanks for the update, @yoki. Blue and red on the left subplots are, presumably, the real labels?

Comment: Correct. Sorry, I forgot to mention it earlier.